# R google maps, ggmap - rendering pdf files is very slow, is there a way make an efficient pdf file?

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2

I'm currently using the get_map function from package ggmap to grab a google map, I then use ggmap and annotate to add points to the plot.  For each call to annotate there is roughly 1000 points being added, and I call annotate around 100 times.  After saving the output to pdf the rendering and subsequent interaction with the pdf is very slow.  Is there a good way to save to pdf from the quartz or X11 device that will have the same resolution but render faster?  And/Or is there a way of using ggmap to create efficient maps?

Comment: Can you clarify whether its (a) saving the plot from R to disc, or (b) viewing the resulting PDF file in a viewer, that is slower than you'd like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reduce pdf file size of plot in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521299/reduce-pdf-file-size-of-plot-in-r).  See @hadley's answer.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364288/what-hardware-limits-plotting-speed-in-r

Comment: @joran they are both fairly slow, but I'm more concerned about viewing in pdf.

Comment: Ok, if viewing the resulting file is the primary problem, then I think your only options are to either make pdfs with fewer elements (fewer points) or get a computer with more RAM/faster processor, etc. Though as others noted, compression will also help, by reducing the file size.