# x-axis label text size is not reduced while y-axis is reduced

Tags: r, resize, axis

I've been trying to reduce the size of the labels in x-axis so that all the values appear, but don't know why it doesn't work. Also I try to use `mtext` to put only one x-axis label for all three graphs but it also didn't work. Could anyone please help?
Here is the data named benefitlossr

```
Region      ChangeNPV   ChangeNPVadjusted   ChangeHC    Scenario
Carabooda   13.47257941 7.430879051 0.1 S1-2
Carabooda   13.47151427 7.530120412 0.055   S2-3
Carabooda   14.83684617 8.940968276 0.056   S3-4
Carabooda   15.37691395 9.617533157 0.056   S4-5
Neerabup    3.499426472 2.232675752 0.01    S1-2
Neerabup    3.499596203 2.23966378  0.01    S2-3
Neerabup    3.836086106 2.566649186 0.01    S3-4
Neerabup    3.995114558 2.725839325 0.02    S4-5
Nowergup    3.513500149 1.700543633 0.02    S1-2
Nowergup    3.513585809 1.710386802 0.01    S2-3
Nowergup    3.850266108 2.034689127 0.02    S3-4
Nowergup    4.009112768 2.194350586 0.02    S4-5
```

This is my code

```
Caraboodaloss <- subset(Benefitlossr, Region=="Carabooda")
Neerabuploss <- subset(Benefitlossr, Region=="Neerabup")
Nowerguploss <- subset(Benefitlossr, Region=="Nowergup")

Caraboodaloss

tiff("barplot.tiff", width=130, height=50, units='mm', res=300)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 0.2))

mxCarabooda <- t(as.matrix(Caraboodaloss[,2:3]))
Caraboodaloss$Label <- paste(Caraboodaloss$Scenario, Caraboodaloss$ChangeHC)
colnames(mxCarabooda) <- Caraboodaloss$Label
colours=c("gray63","gray87")

barplot(mxCarabooda, main='Carabooda', ylab='Profit loss ($m)',
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut', beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30),cex.lab=0.7, cex.sub=0.7, cex.axis=0.7)

legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), cex=0.6, pch=15)

mxNeerabup <- t(as.matrix(Neerabuploss[,2:3]))
Neerabuploss$Label <- paste(Neerabuploss$Scenario, Caraboodaloss$ChangeHC)
colnames(mxNeerabup) <- Neerabuploss$Label

colours=c("gray63","gray87")

barplot(mxNeerabup,main='Neerabup', ylab='', 
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut', beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30), cex.lab=0.7, cex.sub=0.7, cex.axis=0.7)
legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), cex=0.6, pch=15)

mxNowergup <- t(as.matrix(Nowerguploss[,2:3]))

Nowerguploss$Label <- paste(Nowerguploss$Scenario,Nowerguploss$ChangeHC)
colnames(mxNowergup) <- Nowerguploss$Label
colours=c("gray63","gray87")

barplot(mxNowergup,main='Nowergup', ylab='', 
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut',beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30), cex.lab=0.7, cex.sub=0.7, cex.axis=0.7)
legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), cex=0.6, pch=15)

dev.off()
```

this is the result I get

[image]

x-axis labels are too big even though y-axis label size is reduced. As the result, not all values can be displayed in the axis. If possible, I would like all the labels of x-axis to be clearly seen in the graph. I can't change the size of width and height because it's required.

Comment: Please do not post an image of data: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Another suggestion: reduce your code significantly. If you solve your issue for one of the three bar plots, then you will be able to apply it to all others, so please do not give us unnecessary code. (Often, if it needs to scroll, it may be too much. Not always, for sure. But seeing that much code does deter many from even reading further.)

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. Cos I also want to show the problem given constraint on the exported requirement. And if possible the one common x-lab for all three graphs. For data, I'll fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `mtext` to get global axis labels is a good idea. You could also do this with the legend. For the tick labels I'd recommend to turn them by 90°. Therefore, the overall readability should have improved. (Could be even better fine-tuned than my solution provided.)

First we put the matrices into a list and use `barplot` in a `lapply` to save typing.

```
L <- list(mxCarabooda=mxCarabooda, mxNeerabup=mxNeerabup, mxNowergup=mxNeerabup)
```

Into the `par` options we include `oma` to enlarge outer margins, and `xpd` to place text and legends anywhere. In the `barplot` we switch off the x axis and add them manually. Use [lossless compression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3596743/6574038) by setting `compression="lzw"`.

```
tiff("barplot.tiff", width=260, height=100, units='mm', res=300, compression="lzw")
par(mfrow=c(1,3), mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1, oma=c(6, 4, 0, 0), xpd=TRUE)

lapply(seq_along(L), function(x) {
  b1 <- barplot(L[[x]], main=gsub("^mx", "", names(L)[x]), beside=TRUE, xaxt="n",
                col=c("gray63","gray87"), ylim=c(0,30))
  axis(1, at=apply(b1, 2, mean), labels=colnames(L[[x]]), 
       tick=FALSE, line=FALSE, las=2)
})

mtext('Change in water table at each level of GW cut', side=1, outer=TRUE, line=1)  # x-lab
mtext('Profit loss ($m)', side=2, outer=TRUE, line=1)                               # y-lab
legend(-16.5, -15, bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), cex=1.2, pch=15, horiz=TRUE, xpd=NA)           

dev.off()
```

***Result***

[image]

However, for the solution to work, I had to at least double the size of the `tiff` size because the figure margins get too large. However, the aspect ratio remains the same, which should be *more important*. Could you check that with your journal? Maybe you could also use `pdf("barplot.pdf", width=13, height=5)` instead of the `tiff(.)` line.

---

***Data***

```
mxCarabooda <- structure(c(13.47258, 7.430879, 13.47151, 7.53012, 14.83685, 
                           8.940968, 15.37691, 9.617533), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
                             c("ChangeNP", "ChangeNP.1"), c("Sl-2 0.1", "S2-3 0.055", 
                                                            "S3-4 0.056", "S4-5 0.056")))
mxNeerabup <- structure(c(3.499426, 2.232676, 3.499596, 2.239664, 3.836086, 
                          2.566649, 3.995115, 2.725839), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
                            c("ChangeNP", "ChangeNP.1"), c("Sl-2 0.1", "S2-3 0.055", 
                                                           "S3-4 0.056", "S4-5 0.056")))

mxNowergup <- structure(c(3.5135, 1.700544, 3.513586, 1.710387, 3.850266, 2.034689, 
                          4.009113, 2.194351), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
                            c("ChangeNP", "ChangeNP.1"), c("Sl-2 0.02", "S2-3 0.01", 
                                                           "S3-4 0.02", "S4-5 0.02")))
```

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf, but the size of the figure is required by the journal and I cannot change that :(

Comment: I see. I've edited my answer. Shouldn't the aspect ratio be decisive instead of the exact dimensions? Ask your journal. If you use `pdf(.)` you get a vector graphic that is resizable without any loss of quality.

Comment: That actually looks very good. Another option that I can think of is to put the second value (scenario) of the x-axis below the first value (HCchange). But I also fail to do that. What do you think?

Comment: To be sure, would this imply that in the plot the grey and darkgrey bars will change sides? In this case, after putting matrices into the list, do `L <- lapply(L, function(x) x[2:1, ])`. Does this help?

Comment: By the way if I want to put each variable as 1 row in x-axis should I ask another question or can be explained here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could also have set parameters just in the initial `par` call instead of in each barplot separately and also set `las=2` to get perpendicular orientation of tick labels.

```
tiff("barplot.tiff", width=130, height=50, units='mm', res=300)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 0.2), cex.lab=0.5, cex.sub=0.7, cex.axis=0.5, las=2)

mxCarabooda <- t(as.matrix(Caraboodaloss[,2:3]))
Caraboodaloss$Label <- paste(Caraboodaloss$Scenario, Caraboodaloss$ChangeHC)
colnames(mxCarabooda) <- Caraboodaloss$Label
colours=c("gray63","gray87")

barplot(mxCarabooda, main='Carabooda', ylab='Profit loss ($m)',
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut', beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30))

legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), cex=0.6, pch=15)

mxNeerabup <- t(as.matrix(Neerabuploss[,2:3]))
Neerabuploss$Label <- paste(Neerabuploss$Scenario, Caraboodaloss$ChangeHC)
colnames(mxNeerabup) <- Neerabuploss$Label

colours=c("gray63","gray87")

barplot(mxNeerabup,main='Neerabup', ylab='', 
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut', beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30) )
legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), cex=0.6, pch=15)

mxNowergup <- t(as.matrix(Nowerguploss[,2:3]))

Nowerguploss$Label <- paste(Nowerguploss$Scenario,Nowerguploss$ChangeHC)
colnames(mxNowergup) <- Nowerguploss$Label
colours=c("gray63","gray87")

barplot(mxNowergup,main='Nowergup', ylab='', 
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut',beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30) )
legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), cex=0.6, pch=15)

dev.off()
```

[image]